# GitHub letting me push commits despite not being logged in

Tags: git, github

tl;dr: Commits are not connected to my GitHub-account, but Git isn't asking me to log in when making the commits or pushing, even when the repository is set to private.

when I check my repository, I see that my commits are done with my username, but the commit doesn't seem to be associated with my profile, because clicking on the username in the commit history does not send me to my profile (it's just plain text without any hyperlink).

From that, I am assuming that I somehow managed to push to my repository despite not being logged into GitHub on my machine.

Since I want my commits to be associated to my profile, I've been trying to log into Github through Git on my PC, but all the documentation I could find on it says that Git will ask me to log in when trying to push, but it doesn't, even when I set the repository to private.

**How can I get git to give me a login prompt so that my commits are properly associated to my profile?**

If it helps, I've previously been using Git for projects on my old University's GitLab server, from which some old settings might have survived even after reinstalling Git on my PC.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
What I did wrong in this specific case:
For some reason, when setting my username and E-Mail-adress, I did it by doing `git config --global user.[setting] = [value]`, which made the values an `=` sign. I noticed it because the `=`-sign was my username on GitHub, which I fixed, but I never noticed that it was the same thing for my E-Mail-adress.

Comment: Don’t worry. Your GitHub is probably fine. Make sure that GitHub knows about all the emails you that use in your commits in order to make sure that it associates all commits with your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things going on here.  First, the information in your commits is set by Git's configuration, usually via the `user.name` and `user.email` information.  `user.name` is conventionally a personal name (that is, a form of the name other humans call you), not a username, and has no relation to authentication whatever.  `user.email` is the email associated with your commits.  None of this requires authentication in any way.

You can also have credentials for pushing, which may be an SSH key or, for GitHub, a token for pushing over HTTPS.  If you're not being prompted, then you're either using an SSH key without a password, or you have a credential manager that's saving your credentials.  Both are fine.

Note that these are completely unrelated.  You can push commits from any user whatever, because Git is designed for a workflow where people send patches to a maintainer, who then applies those patches, and being able to push only your commits wouldn't be helpful in that case.

Now, the way GitHub associates commits with a profile is via the email address in the commits, which is usually set with `user.email` defined above.  If you're not seeing your commits associated with your GitHub username, then that's because the email address you're using in your commits isn't associated with your GitHub account.  If you add it, that should end up with your commits properly associated.